# Detect if userspace module dies unexpectidly from Linux driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver

I have a Linux driver which allows userspace applications to register some application specific data which would effect how the driver functions.   Typically, the userspace application would deregister its information before exiting.   If the application were to crash however, then there would be no way to deregister the information, and there would be a memory leak.  I'm wondering if it's possible to detect from kernel space, if a userspace application has exited unexpectedly.

Comment: How about using a char driver, with the userspace application keeping the device descriptor open? If the application crashes, the kernel closes the descriptor (and unmaps any maps) automatically. Furthermore, registering/mapping (via `mmap()`) the app-specific data would be very simple. (I didn't put this as an answer, because it is a way to basically avoid the problem you're having. I'm pretty sure there is a way to hook the application task/process in the kernel to get notified of it exiting, I'm just not sure of the details at this moment.)

Answer (score 2):

struct task_struct *task = current; would give you the pointer to the current task. task->comm and task->pid will give the name and PID for the process. When the userspace application calls your driver for registering its data (Assuming you are using a character device interface, write) you can add the pid to the list. Run a timer and whenever the timer expires, in the callback, initialize the task pointer again to current and go through the circular linked list by task = task->next until task becomes current again and see if all the pids in the list still exist in the kernel task list. If you find anything missing,

Comment: Not keen on polling (I would rather be notified), but it sounds like there's nothing cleaner.

Comment: If you can recompile the kernel, then there are multiple options like adding some hooks/callbacks from kernel/exit.c. But if there is no such privileges, I am not able to think of a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the method in my previous answer, instead of polling, you can use `find_task_by_vpid(pid);` to get the task structure for the task directly. Comment says this must be called under `rcu_read_lock()`.

Another option would be to implement a generic netlink socket communication between application and kernel module. Here the application will have to respond to the kernel messages. That would be more work compared to the first approach where if find_task_by_vpid() returns NULL, you can conclude your userspace process is dead.